# Table of integrals with Euler's constant gamma.

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm working on a large table of integrals with Euler's constant $\gamma=0.577...$ It's a very interesting point, that a lot of integrals are found in similar tables like Gradshteyn-Ryzhik, but are not able to calculate with maple or mathematica. For example
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{\cosh^2 x}dx = \log\pi - 2\log2 - \gamma$$
and the similar integral
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\log x\left(\frac1{\sinh^2} - \frac1{x^2}\right)dx = \gamma-\log\pi$$
Question 1. It is possible to get the first integral from
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\left(\frac1{e^x-1} - \frac1{xe^x}\right)dx = \gamma$$
At StackExchange I found this proof, which could be simplify.
[Integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\cosh^2x} \ \mathrm{d}x = \log\frac {\pi}4- \gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786257)
Question 2. Know somebody a proof? It's is easy to get second integral by subtracting both.

Question 3. Are the newest Versions of maple or Mathematica able to do this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and also, aren't those two integrals exactly the same?

Comment: I'm sorry. The entry wasn't finish.

Comment: So put it in short you want to prove that  $$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{\cosh^2 x}dx = \log\pi - 2\log2 - \gamma$$ Using the known result of: $$\int\limits_0^\infty\left(\frac1{e^x-1} - \frac1{xe^x}\right)dx = \gamma$$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But I have found a proof on Stackexange with I have add above. But this proof maybe improved.